# Merge 2 tables in the same database by same primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables in a database:

```
users:
id (PKEY)
username
display_name
...

users_private:
id (PKEY FOREIGN KEY) -- referencing User
last_ip
created_at
...
```

I want to combine the two tables and drop users_private.

I need to append the columns of users_private into users (merging them). So it would become in this case:

```
users:
id (PKEY)
username
display_name
last_ip
created_at
...
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Create new columns in the dstination table (ALTER TABLE) then copy the data to them (UPDATE).

Comment: Do you really want to combine the two tables and then drop `users_private`? Or do you just want to query the data?

Comment: @Colin'tHart The first one. I want to combine the two tables and drop users_private.

Comment: @Akina Yes I have added all the columns in users_private to users table. But how can I copy all the data in users_private to users now, without doing all the INSERTs manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
-- add columns
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD COLUMN last_ip {definition},
    ADD COLUMN created_at {definition};

-- copy data
UPDATE users
SET last_ip  = users_private.last_ip,
    created_at = users_private.created_at
FROM users_private 
WHERE id = users_private.id
```

Comment: `WHERE users.id = ...`